Cloudflare KV worker to return compressed objects
I'm working on a Cloudflare Hono api site, where I want to fetch ZLIB items from a Cloudflare KV.
Items are stored as, eg. <key_name>_chunk_0, <key_name>_chunk_1, etc.
Ideally I want to return the items as a list of compressed objects, but will be satisfied with a single zipped object (I'll be decompressing on the client).
So far, I get empty stuff returned to the client. I've checked namespace and access to the KV store and all that works fine.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import { Hono } from 'hono';

const app = new Hono();

async function fetchFromKV(env, baseKey) {
  const chunks = [];
  let chunkIndex = 0;
  
  while (true) {
    const chunkKey = `${baseKey}_chunk_${chunkIndex}`;
    const chunkData = await env.KEYNAMESPACE.get(chunkKey, "arrayBuffer");
    
    if (chunkData === null) {
      // No more chunks found, break the loop
      break;
    } 
    chunks.push(chunkData);
    chunkIndex++;
  }
  return chunks;
}

app.get('/api/getHello', async (c) => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchFromKV(c.env, 'key-for-zipped-item');  // Use await to fetch data

    return c.json({
      message: 'Here is your data!',
      data: data
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return c.json({ error: e.message }, 500);
  }
});

export default app;

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!
EDIT: Also tried this with no success with GZIP item:
app.get('/api/getGzipItem', async (c) => {


 // Basic auth check (you may want to adjust this based on your actual auth setup)
  const key = '<key_name>_chunk_0';
  const gzipData = await c.env.RESSADA.get(key, "arrayBuffer");

  if (gzipData === null) {
    return c.json({ message: 'Item not found' }, 404);
  }
  c.header('Content-Type', 'application/gzip');
  c.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  // Return the compressed data as a raw response
  return c.body(gzipData);
});


Logs on both server and client side don't show useful debugging infos?
